# How to know if a value was injected or updated in Eclipse RCP 4?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I need to track an object was injected/updated in the context. The object was created in another plugin then set to context using a name. I can get out this object using this name in a handler. I want to add some listener to this object in another plugin if it was injected/updated. I tried with RunAndTrack in an addon but the code didn't run. Please help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'injected/updated'?

Comment: Example: in a plugin, I create an object then set to the context by a name. In another plugin (B), I can get this object by the name in a handler. Now I want to add a key listener to this (if a new object has been injected to the key or changed). But I don't know where. If I inject this object, I just receive null.

Comment: I can resolve this using setting RunAndTrack  in an addon. I don't know why it didn't work yesterday.

Comment: if you use the 'Inject' annotation on a setter method (with a 'Named' annotated param), you have your "listener".